# What will happen if Brownian motion is taken iteratively (i.e. W(W(t)), W(W(W(t))), ...)?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

We consider a one dimensional bi-directional standard Brownian motion $\{W(t)\}_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ with $W(0) = 0$. **Then what can we say about $\{W(W(t))\}$? Is it a martingale? Is it Markovian? And what about $\{W(W(W(t)))\}$, $\{W(W(W(W(t))))\}$, and so on?**

I tried a simple MATLAB algorithm to simulate $W^{(K)}(t)$. It seems that the process converge to something that oscillates and jumps crazily. But I am not sure whether my simulation is correct since I am using a linear interpolation while the Brownian motion is not piecewise differentiable. Therefore, I also want to know: **is there any way to simulate these processes more accurately?**

```
clear; clc;
T = 10;
N = 1500;
x = linspace(-T, T, 2 * N + 1);
BM = zeros(1, 2 * N + 1);
for i = 1 : 2 * N
    BM(i + 1) = BM(i) + randn * sqrt(T / N);
end
BM = BM - BM(N + 1);
% plot(x, BM);
BMi = BM;
K = 64;
for j = 2 : K
    BMi_new = interp1(x, BMi, BM);
    disp(norm(BMi_new - BMi))
    BMi = BMi_new;
end
plot(x, BMi);
```

Comment: Since W(W(t)) samples W(s) at random  points s,  its a generator for a discrete jump  function over the sampling points x with a   $\sqrt x$ histogram and no continuity at all. Taking more and more square roots and refinements it should converge to 1 in probability. But in the discrete approximations on finite intervals the nesting process is undefined. Limits need careful sampling remapping prescriptions as e.g.  present in Ito and Stratonovich integrals with sampling at the next left point or as mean of left and right points   in the discrete list representations of a single  random path W.